# Implement Auto color (photoshop tool) on android

Tags: java, android, image, image-processing, colors

I want to use the auto-color tool (photoshop, under Image tab) on the android.
Is their a way to implement this tool/option into android with code or does android already has this kind of option in a librabry?

So when I open a picture, then when I hit a button, it should use the auto-color on the image (ImageView).

Thanks for the help already

this is the problem:
I got a green scanner, it is a scanner that scans the pixels green, and then shows the % green that is on the image.
However when you take a picture of some grass when the sun is shining the app detects more green then you take one in the shadow, but in real, their is the same amount of green (grass).

And with the tool in photoshop (auto-color) it manipulates the "sun" really good, after few pictures (tests) the auto-color does it better then when I do it manually, so that is the reason I want to try to get this tool on the android somehow.

I didn't tried to implement auto-color in the android yet because I just don't if their is something like that. I now have 2 pictures (taken at same time, 1 in shadow and 1 in the sun) and I try to manipulate the one that I took in the sun, so it looks like the one taking in the shadow. So it gives (almost) the same amount of % green with my green scanner app.

PS, Mine Internet connection goes down now for few minutes, so I maybe won't see this post (answers) right-away

Comment: what you have tried, kindly put some effort on your question thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any build-in way to do this on Android, so you'll probably have to do the algorithm yourself.

But, you could start off by getting inspired on how Gimp does it, by looking through the source code. Otherwise wikipedia has a good article on the subject - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_balance